# SQL server 複数テーブルに同時にINSERTしたい

Tags: c#, sql-server

SQL server 2016 standardで、複数のテーブルに一つのSQL文で、同時にINSERTできるならしたいのですが、何かやり方はありますでしょうか？

例えば、複数テーブルを参照したVIEWを作成してVIEWに対してINSERT文を発行すればINSERTできますか？
sumとかの関数はViewやテーブルには使いません。

一つ目のテーブルにデータを登録する際シーケンスを番号を発行しますが２つ目のテーブルにも同じシーケンス番号を登録したいのです。

順番に複数テーブル登録するのがプログラム仕様的に難しいため質問させていただきました。
　宜しくお願いいたします。

プログラムはc#で作成してます。

Comment: トランザクションを使用しても「順番に複数テーブル登録するのがプログラム仕様的に難しい」のでしょうか？

Comment: 複数行の登録処理をテーブル単位で実施しているため、次のテーブルに登録する際、シーケンス番号に同じ値を使用する場合、一つ目のテーブルからシーケンス番号を取得する必要があります。取得すればできますが処理のオーバーヘッドを少なくするため一度に登録できないか検討中です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

いくつかのアプローチがあります。

#### ストアドプロシージャ

順当に行うのであれば、SQL Server上にストアドプロシージャを作成することです。C#から必要なパラメーターを与えて呼び出すことができます。

#### `OUTPUT`句 その１

SQL Serverには[`OUTPUT`句](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)という機能があります。この機能を使うと`INSERT`された結果行をそのまま読み出すことができます。データ量を抑えるためにシーケンス番号だけを読み出すこともできます。C#からは`INSERT`文を[`SqlCommand.ExecuteReader`メソッド](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?view=netframework-4.7.2)で実行することで読み出せます。

#### `OUTPUT`句 その２

`OUTPUT`句には更に`INTO`で指定したテーブルへ挿入を行う機能があります。ただしいくつかの条件があるため、利用できないかもしれません。

---

> 複数テーブルを参照したVIEWを作成してVIEWに対してINSERT文を発行すればINSERTできますか？

SQL Serverには[更新可能なビュー](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#updatable-views)という機能はあります。しかし「1 つのベース テーブルのみの列を参照している」という条件があるため、質問のケースでは利用できません。